# JSF 2 composite:actionSource exposing commandButtons in ui:repeat

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

In my composite component, I have a ui:repeat that has, among other static things, a command button, like this:

```
 <ui:repeat var="article" value="#{cc.attrs.articleList}">
     <strong>Aricle: #{article}</strong>
     <h:commandButton id="addToFavs" value="Subscribe" binding="..." type="..." >
         <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{article}" target="..." />
     </h:commandButton >
 </ui:repeat>
```

Now, I'd like to expose this event in the composite interface, so that in my page, I may attach event listeners and tie in f:ajax.

Had it been outside of ui:repeat (i.e., there existed only one such button), that would have been quite easy, like this:

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:actionSource name="addToFavs" targets="#{cc.clientId}:addToFavs" />
  <composite:clientBehavior name="ajax" default="true"
                              event="action" targets="#{cc.clientId}:addToFavs"/>
</composite:interface>
```

But that fails in this case, because there's no one component by that ID (*addToFavs*), but rather a bunch of them. Do you know how should I expose these buttons in the interface?

Regards,

Pradyumna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating this post with my best guess, just in case someone wants to know if I could achieve it:

No I couldn't do it. Looks like we can't do it. We can only expose components whose IDs relative to the composite component are known to the component author apriori.