# How do I target multiple commandlLinks (genereated by <ui:repeat>) from a <composite:clientBehaviour>

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, composite-component

I have a JSF composite component with multiple `<h:commandLink>`s (generated in a `<ui:repeat>`) and I would like the component to fire a `change` event if any of these links is clicked.

The following code is a minimal example of my component. With just one single link everything works as expected but the automatic generated ids of the `<ui:repeat>` seem to break it.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="click" targets="linkID"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.myList}" var="item">
        <h:commandLink id="linkID"
                       action="#{bean.doSomething(item)}">
            do it
        </h:commandLink>
    </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: Seems it does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075602/jsf-2-compositeactionsource-exposing-commandbuttons-in-uirepeat